# HTML element's value property is giving undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is totally mysterious. I checked everything, googled everything, but looks like this should work. I've done same things in my code with others html elements and they all give me the values, but this time I'm getting undefined for this particular HTML element. The snippet of code below:

```
<div class="pianoKeyboard">
    <button id="octaveUp" value="off">Octave Up</button>
    <button id="octaveDown" value="off">Octave Down</button>
    <div id="octaveNum" value='0'>Default</div>
```

---

```
var octaveNumber = document.getElementById("octaveNum");

    octaveup.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (booleanVal == false) {
        booleanVal = true;
        console.log(octaveNumber.value);
```

Do you see any problem? Because I don't. I can `console.log` the element itself without the value, but if I add `.value` to it, I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `<div>` elements do not have a `value` attribute. [It is only for a selected subset of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes): `<button>`, `<option>`, `<input>`, `<li>`, `<meter>`, `<progress>`, and `<param>`.

You can store the value as a [HTML5 `data-` attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), i.e.:

```
<div id="octaveNum" data-value='0'>Default</div>
```

The value of the `data-` attribute can simply be accessed programmatically using:

```
document.getElementById('octaveNum').dataset.value
```

The `data-` attribute offers you tremendous flexibility over the naming of variables: it doesn't even have to be `data-value`. For example, if you want to store the default and current octaves, you can choose to store it as `data-default-octave` and `data-current-octave`, and access it as `selector.dataset.defaultOctave` and `selector.dataset.currentOctave` respectively (note the conversion of dash-delimited attribute name in HTML5 to camelCase keys in JS).

> Data attribute names which contain hyphens will be stripped of their hyphens and converted to CamelCase.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var octaveNumber = document.getElementById("octaveNum");
var octaveUp = document.getElementById("octaveUp");
octaveUp.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(octaveNumber.dataset.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="pianoKeyboard">
  <button id="octaveUp" value="off">Octave Up</button>
  <button id="octaveDown" value="off">Octave Down</button>
  <div id="octaveNum" data-value='0'>Default</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And I assume to add +1 to the Div data-value, we first have to parse it as an integer, right? Thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: @Limpuls That is generally a wise idea :) since users that are a bit savvy might try to be funny and modify the DOM attribute values. You can simply use `+octaveNumber.dataset.value` to coerce it to a number (e.g. `var octave = +octaveNumber.dataset.value`), or use the more verbose `Number(octaveNumber.dataset.value)` :)

Answer (score 0):

`div` element have no `value` attribute, so you can't use `octaveNumber.value` to get it